# PyUSB Linux USB device re-claimed by kernel

Tags: python, linux, usb

I am trying to communicate with a label printer over USB.  I have it sort of working!  It seems to me like the kernel (or some other driver) is re-claiming the USB device while I am trying to use it.  I get use of it for a few seconds, but any longer and the device appears to be unavailable.  The device is registered as a printer (class 7).

If I run the following code it works as expected and I get the response data back from the printer, but if I break point it anywhere, I get a few seconds to step through but if I leave it any longer, a usb.core.USBError: [Errno 19] No such device (it may have been disconnected) exception is raised.

Is there a way to tell the kernel or other drivers to leave this device alone?  Or a better method to access its read/write endpoints maybe through the printer driver instead of low level USB?

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1203, idProduct=0x0273)
if dev is None :
    raise ValueError("USB device not found")

wasAttached = False
if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0):
    try:
        dev.detach_kernel_driver(0)
        usb.util.claim_interface(dev, 0)
        wasAttached = True
        print("kernel driver detached")
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        sys.exit("Could not detach kernel driver: ")
else:
    print("no kernel driver attached")

cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
if cfg.bConfigurationValue != 1 :
    dev.set_configuration(1)

cmd = bytes([27, ord('!'), ord('S'), ord('\r'), ord('\n')])
l = dev.write(1, cmd)
print('Sent + ' + str(l))

readBuf = bytes(256)
n = dev.read(130, 256)
print('Read + ' + str(n))

usb.util.release_interface(dev, 0)
if wasAttached :
    dev.attach_kernel_driver(0)
```

Gives the following response, showing that driver was attached to the kernel at the start, and that data is sent to and received from the printer while I have it.

```
kernel driver detached
Sent + 5
Read + array('B', [2, 64, 64, 64, 64, 3, 13, 10])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am still no further on with this.  Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Yeah, still stuck on this...